# Why can methods in Enumerable be without a method body?

Tags: c#, linq

I was confused by this problem. Traditionally, if I write a method like this:

```
public static class MyClass
{
    public static int myMethod(this int x, Func<int, bool> evaluate);
}
```

I will get a compile error, said:

> 'ExtentionMethods.MyClass.myMethod(int, System.Func)' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial

This is understandable. But I looked at the Enumerable class under namespace System.Linq. I found all methods have no method body, for example:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate);
```

And there is no any compile error for it. Why?

What is the reason?

Comment: Second line of code you've posted does not compile and produces exactly the same error you get for the first one... Are you sure you actually tried to compile that code (and not looking at some decompiled code or documentation)?

Comment: You looked at the wrong file.  That was a *reference assembly*, not the assembly that's actually used at runtime.  Or possibly the fake decompiled metadata you'd get in VS when you use the GoTo Definition command.  The .NET 4 reference assemblies are used only at compile-time and only contain the declarations, bodies are empty.  The runtime assembly is retrieved from the GAC.  Be sure to look at those, you can navigate c:\windows\microsoft.net\assembly at will.  Or use the [Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,577032c8811e20d3).

Answer (score 4):

It's because you looked at metadata. Metadata just describe interface, not an implementation.

You can write methods without body only in interfaces and abstract classes. But if you want to use it you need to implement them in derived classes.

More information about abstract methods: [MSDN abstract methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664435(v=vs.71).aspx) 
and interfaces: [interface (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

> I looked Enumerable class under namespace System.Linq, I found all methods have no method body

You didn't say what implementation you are looking at, but at least for CoreFX, it is not true. The implementation for `System.Linq.Enumerable.Where` is right where you would expect it, in [`src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Where.cs`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Where.cs#L13-L44):

> ```
> public static IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
> {
>     if (source == null)
>     {
>         throw Error.ArgumentNull(nameof(source));
>     }
>
>     if (predicate == null)
>     {
>         throw Error.ArgumentNull(nameof(predicate));
>     }
>
>     Iterator<TSource> iterator = source as Iterator<TSource>;
>     if (iterator != null)
>     {
>         return iterator.Where(predicate);
>     }
>
>     TSource[] array = source as TSource[];
>     if (array != null)
>     {
>         return new WhereArrayIterator<TSource>(array, predicate);
>     }
>
>     List<TSource> list = source as List<TSource>;
>     if (list != null)
>     {
>         return new WhereListIterator<TSource>(list, predicate);
>     }
>
>     return new WhereEnumerableIterator<TSource>(source, predicate);
> }
> ```

In the Microsoft .NET Reference Source, it is in [`System/Linq/Enumerable.cs`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,15) in the `System.Core` project:

> ```
> public static IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate) {
>     if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
>     if (predicate == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("predicate");
>     if (source is Iterator<TSource>) return ((Iterator<TSource>)source).Where(predicate);
>     if (source is TSource[]) return new WhereArrayIterator<TSource>((TSource[])source, predicate);
>     if (source is List<TSource>) return new WhereListIterator<TSource>((List<TSource>)source, predicate);
>     return new WhereEnumerableIterator<TSource>(source, predicate);
> }
> ```

In Mono, the implementation used to be in [`mcs/class/System.Core/System.Linq/Enumerable.cs`](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/31b143fdc1eb1859a7172b36b8eabcf693998116/mcs/class/System.Core/System.Linq/Enumerable.cs#L3099-L3109), before they switched to the open-sourced implementation from Microsoft:

> ```
> public static IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource> (this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
> {
>   Check.SourceAndPredicate (source, predicate);
>
>   // It cannot be IList<TSource> because it may break on user implementation
>   var array = source as TSource[];
>   if (array != null)
>       return CreateWhereIterator (array, predicate);
>
>   return CreateWhereIterator (source, predicate);
> }
> ```

I was unable to find a single .NET implementation, where the method you showed is abstract. In all implementations I could find, it is concretely implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Konstantin Zadiran already told you what you are probably looking at, metadata.

A method without a body is essentially an abstract method (Of course you have to also add the `abstract` keyword to mark it as one). Only abstract classes and interfaces can contain abstract methods. Partial methods are another type of method without a body.